# How to Create a Separated Class for Button Handlers in Java?

Tags: java, class, handler

I'm a self-taught programmer and currently working with creating a simple Calculator with GUI in Java (from scratch). I just want to know how to separate my handlers for the action of buttons to another class because I think it'll look much neat and easier to use (Separating GUI from Engine).

In my GUI Class I coded(Testing only to the btnoperators '+, '-', 'x', '/', '<='):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

public JPanel genOperators()
{
  JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 5, 1 ) );

  for( int i = 12; i <= 16; i++ )
  {
   panel.add( btnKeyChoice[i] );
   btnKeyChoice[i].setBackground( Color.WHITE );
   btnKeyChoice[i].addActionListener( handler ); 
  }
  return panel;
}
```

And in my Handler Class:

```
class Handler extends CalculatorGUI implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
  {
    String operators = ((JButton)ae.getSource()).getText();

    switch(operators)
    {
      case "<=" : txtDisplay.setText( " " );
      break;
  
      case "/" : //txtDisplay.setText( btnKeyChoice[13].getText().append() );
      String initialValue = btnKeyChoice[13].getText(); 
      String newValue = initialValue;
      txtDisplay.setText( initialValue + newValue );
      break;
  
      case "x" : txtDisplay.setText( btnKeyChoice[14].getText() );
      break;
  
      case "-" : txtDisplay.setText( btnKeyChoice[15].getText() );
      break;
  
      case "+" : txtDisplay.setText( btnKeyChoice[16].getText() );
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the above, No errors when I Compile it, But when I run it There are two(2) errors but displays
repeatedly in a lot of times. The two main errors are..

> at CalculatorGUI.(bp1_CalculatorGUI.java:44)
> at Handler.(bp1_CalculatorGUI.java:314)
> at CalculatorGUI.(bp1_CalculatorGUI.java:44)
> at Handler.(bp1_CalculatorGUI.java:314)
> at CalculatorGUI.(bp1_CalculatorGUI.java:44)
> at Handler.(bp1_CalculatorGUI.java:314)
> ...

**I WANT TO 1)Display the value of the button while the button is being clicked.
BUT I GUESS, 2)I just want to know first IF MY HANDLER CLASS CREATION IS CORRECT OR NOT.
Please help, I am learning.**

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It WORKED when I made the 'handler' class as the "inner class" of the class 'CalculatorGUI' But still I don't know why isn't it working if its on separated class.